# Paged table with ASP.NET MVC and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I'm looking for good patterns for implementing a paged table of results in ASP.NET MVC with sorting, filtering, and paging provided via AJAX.  It seems to me that I should have my controller actions provide only the data and not mark up to maintain the separation of concerns -- so the Ajax callback would provide new table data and pager settings which the client would use to re-render the table.  Alternatively, I could use have the controller return a partial view that I simply replace inside a container on the page.

I'm new to the ASP.NET MVC world, so I'd be interested in hearing opinions and other alternatives as well.

How would you go about doing this?

I'm also interested in hearing about jquery table plugins that work well with Ajax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few options to checkout:

- [jQuery Flexigrid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/MVCFlexigrid.aspx)
- [Yahoo DataTable](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/datatable/)
- [Ext JS](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/array-grid.html)

I'm leaning towards Yahoo's solution atm since it offers much more than just a grid control.

Comment: Hi @ToddSmith - any idea about [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34003053/2404470)

Answer (score 2):

[JQuery Grid](http://www.trirand.com/blog/) appears to do everything that you are asking for.  It has quite nice documentation and examples.  I have not yet used it but I plan to very soon.

Answer (score 2):

Dont use tablesorter. Its very hard to re render the table with paging and sorting while u delete some records from the  table. I had a very hard time with that.

Answer (score 0):

I really like [tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

It's more light-weight and a bit easier to manage...

Answer (score 0):

I like to use telerik extension for MVC, they are open source and have lots of exemple :
http://www.telerik.com/products/aspnet-mvc/grid.aspx