# Methods to create a navigation for table with many entries

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, navigation

I have follow problem: in my table into View I have more than 50 entries (rows).
I want to show just a 8 entries pro time, and above the table make some kind of navigation (like **1** 2 3 4 5 ..) and if I need to see next 8 entries I'm clicking on the number 2, i see them. I don't know how can I do all this. Has somebody any idea?

I'm working with MVC, and I want too that this solution is dynamic, that by more entries automatically will have longer navigation 56 enties = (1 2 3 4 5 6 7).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement paging for your table.

Check out these answers

[Paged table with ASP.NET MVC and AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/286022/paged-table-with-asp-net-mvc-and-ajax)

[Paging & Sorting grids with ASP.Net MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/496470/paging-sorting-grids-with-asp-net-mvc)